# Why isn't this FindBugs warning suppressed?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, findbugs

I'm trying to suppress a FindBugs warning in one of my unit tests:

```
@SuppressFBWarnings(value = "DMI_DOH",
                    justification = "It's sensical when declaring expectations.")
@Test
public void ctor_checksForNullArguments() {
    new Expectations(Preconditions.class) {
        {
            Preconditions.checkNotNull("DUMMY");   // D'oh! A nonsensical invocation…
            this.result = "DUMMY";

            Preconditions.checkNotNull("(dummy)"); // D'oh! A nonsensical invocation…
            this.result = "(dummy)";
        }
    };

    new InfixSymbolTest.DummySymbol();
}
```

I can only assume that I'm doing so incorrectly, as the warning is still reported via both the Eclipse feature and Gradle plugin.  Help?

- JDK: 1.7.0_51
- Eclipse: 4.3.1
- FindBugs Feature for Eclipse: 2.0.3
- Gradle: 1.12
- FindBugs annotations: 2.0.3
- JUnit: 4.11
- JMockit: 1.12

Comment: Does it silence it if you move the `@SuppressFBWarnings` onto the anonymous inner class instead of the test method?

Comment: BTW, it really _doesn't_ make sense... this would make more sense, IMO: `this.result = Preconditions.checkNotNull("DUMMY");`

Comment: @WilliamPrice — Annotations can't be placed before arbitrary statements (which is all the `new Expecatations` line is).  Assigning it to a local variable and adding the annotation to that doesn't work, either.

Comment: @WilliamPrice — As for rearranging the code, this is setting up mocks.  Making the change you suggest would break the mocks, as you first make the call you want to mock, then declare what you want the mocked invocation to return.

Comment: It's not _simply_ an "arbitrary statement"... you're creating a new (anonymous) class and annotations can generally be placed on classes, though you may be correct that the compiler won't accept it (I've not tried).  The point is, the statements are part of that anonymous class, not your test method, so annotating the test method doesn't affect them.

Comment: I also don't see how my suggestion would "break" anything, the `checkNotNull` method would be called first, with the value of `"DUMMY"`, and then that same value `"DUMMY"` would be assigned to `this.result`.  The difference is that my version correlates to the field assignment (and ensures that `null` is not assigned) where the version you wrote is only correlated in that they _happen_ to use the same literal value.

Comment: @WilliamPrice — JMockit works by inspecting bytecode.  If I make that change, the test begins incorrectly throwing a NullPointerException because it changes the behavior of the mock.

Comment: Fair enough regarding test breakage, though I side w/ FindBugs that (as written, without knowledge of the JMockit "magic") the code doesn't make much sense at all.  Please see my earlier comment regarding the scope of the FB annotation and the scope of the statements it's flagging.

Comment: @WilliamPrice — Promoting the anonymous class to a named class and annotating there does indeed work, though it causes me other problems which are out of scope.  Post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code creates an *anonymous inner class*:

```
new Expectations(Preconditions.class) {
    // ...
};
```

The calls to `Preconditions.checkNotNull` and assignments to `this.result` occur within an initializer block scoped *within the anonymous inner class*.  In order for the `@SuppressFBWarnings` annotation to apply to those statements, the annotation must be placed, at minimum, on the class that contains them.

Though the source code for the anonymous inner class and its statements are physically written within the `ctor_checksForNullArguments` test method, the resulting bytecode is *not actually a part of the test class*, nor that method, and so placing the annotation on the method applies it to the wrong scope.

Since any anonymous inner class can be extracted to either a named (non-anonymous) inner class or even a top-level class, doing so will enable you to place `@SuppressFBAnnotations` on the proper scope: either the entire class, or potentially a more restricted scope such as a particular method or constructor (as needed).

Comment: Simply converting the anonymous class to a named one within `ctor_checksForNullArguments` and annotating does indeed work.  Thanks!